# Use an existing Excel file to save data on and save under a new name

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I am creating a program that takes an Excel file, stamps information on it and saves it in a file location.

I can easily create a new Excel sheet, put information on it and then save it to a file location.  That is not what I need though. In the form, I want it to pull the existing blank Excel file template I have created, stamp the information entered in the form to it, rename the file and save it in a file location (similar to "save as"). That way there will be one blank master template file to get initially.

I cannot figure out how to grab that Excel file and **not** create a new Excel file.

Here is some sample code:

```
If EmployeeInfo.empNameTextBox.Text = "" Or EmployeeInfo.dateBox.Text = "" Then
    'prompt user must include name and date at least to save
    MessageBox.Show("In order to save a file, you must include the name AND the date", "Fill in Name/Date!",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    'minimize the password form and open back up the EmployeeInfo form
    EmployeeInfo.Show()
    Me.Hide()
Else
    'create and save the excel file
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    'Start a new workbook in Excel
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add


    'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the new workbook
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
    oSheet.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    oSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Litoris"
    oSheet.Range("B2").Value = "Mike"

    'Save the Workbook and Quit Excel
    oBook.SaveAs("N:\IT\Device Images\Incomplete\" + EmployeeInfo.empNameTextBox.Text + EmployeeInfo.dateBox.Text)
    oExcel.Quit

    'minimize this form and go back to main form
    ImageTool.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End If
```

To confirm, I do not want to start a new Excel workbook and cannot figure out how to pull my existing file I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add` to 
`oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\FileName.xls")`

And set the right path, as well as the right sheet on the next line! ;)

```
If EmployeeInfo.empNameTextBox.Text = "" Or EmployeeInfo.dateBox.Text = "" Then
    'prompt user must include name and date at least to save
    MessageBox.Show("In order to save a file, you must include the name AND the date", "Fill in Name/Date!",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    'minimize the password form and open back up the EmployeeInfo form
    EmployeeInfo.Show()
    Me.Hide()
Else
    'create and save the excel file
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    'Start a new workbook in Excel
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\FileName.xls")


    'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the new workbook
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
    oSheet.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    oSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Litoris"
    oSheet.Range("B2").Value = "Mike"

    'Save the Workbook and Quit Excel
    oBook.SaveAs("N:\IT\Device Images\Incomplete\" + EmployeeInfo.empNameTextBox.Text + EmployeeInfo.dateBox.Text)
    oExcel.Quit

    'minimize this form and go back to main form
    ImageTool.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

As already stated in [R3uK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4628637/r3uk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581269/6375113) you can use the [Workbooks.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx) method:

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object

oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("filename")
```

I would like to expand on this ever so slightly and suggest that you reference the `Excel` objects directly:

```
Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Workbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("filename")
```

This will help with referencing methods and properties on the Excel objects. Below you will see the difference:

**Indirect Reference:**

[image]

**Direct Reference:**

[image]

> Note you must import the relevant `Microsoft Excel Object Library` into your project. You will also have to add `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop` to your class.

As a side note, if you haven't already, I would strongly suggest turning [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) **On** whilst using the Excel objects:

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.